# How to attach a volume using docker-machine and openstack

Tags: docker, openstack, docker-machine

I am able to create an instance fine using docker-machine and openstack, using `docker-machine create -d openstack <remaining arguments>`, but I was wondering how can I attach a volume to the instance as well.

And if see the help, I don't see any option of attaching a volume,

```
Commands:
  active                Print which machine is active
  config                Print the connection config for machine
  create                Create a machine
  env                   Display the commands to set up the environment for the Docker client
  inspect               Inspect information about a machine
  ip                    Get the IP address of a machine
  kill                  Kill a machine
  ls                    List machines
  provision             Re-provision existing machines
  regenerate-certs      Regenerate TLS Certificates for a machine
  restart               Restart a machine
  rm                    Remove a machine
  ssh                   Log into or run a command on a machine with SSH.
  scp                   Copy files between machines
  mount                 Mount or unmount a directory from a machine with SSHFS.
  start                 Start a machine
  status                Get the status of a machine
  stop                  Stop a machine
  upgrade               Upgrade a machine to the latest version of Docker
  url                   Get the URL of a machine
  version               Show the Docker Machine version or a machine docker version
  help                  Shows a list of commands or help for one command
```